# Why throw does not support for Exception class?

Tags: java

Why throw does does not support for exception type. As Exception is also a type of throwable class.

```
try {
    throw new Exception("demo");
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.out.println("Caught inside fun().");
    throw e; // rethrowing the exception
}
```

Comment: try
        { 
            throw new Exception("demo"); 
        } 
        catch(NullPointerException e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Caught inside fun()."); 
            throw e; // rethrowing the exception 
        }

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). I'm afraid it's not clear what you're asking from what little you've said. Please provide a more thorough description. (You can `throw new Exception("x")` but your question seems to suggest you think you can't.)

Comment: Please edit the question and add all necessary information there, not in the comments. It is currently unclear what you are asking

Comment: To improve your question, use the "edit" link under it, rather than posting code in comments. I've copied that code into the question, but it's still not clear what you're asking.

Comment: What? Please double check that. You can catch EVERYTHING itat is throwable.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?  Does the code you provide not compile?  It should.  Do you think it should catch the exception you are throwing?  It shouldn't.  What behavior are you seeing, and how does that behavior differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your code:

`Exception` is NOT `NullPointerException`.

`NullPointerException` IS an `Exception`

Its like with square and rectangle - every square is a rectangle, but not every rectangle is a square.

Your code catches NPE - and that is not what code is throwing.